# Flask navbar url_for

Tags: flask

Is there a better way to link navbar items in Flask with JinJia2 templating?

I don't want to create a route for every items in my navbar for `render_template` to that HTML page

```
@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

<li><a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Home</a></li>
```

I tried to create another route with variable, but it only works with HTML page under `template` folder's root

```
@main.route('/<page>')
def show(page):
    return render_template('%s.html' % page)

<li><a href="{{ url_for('main.show', page='profile') }}">My Profile</a></li>
```

If I want to get the page under `template/team` folder, it returns 500 error

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('main.show', page='team/members') }}">Members</a></li>
```

Am I doing this the correct to link navbar? How can I fix my route so it will work perfectly, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, variables in routes match strings.

```
@main.route('/<page>')
```

is the same thing as

```
@main.route('/<string:page>')
```

In order to include a directory you need to tell it to match a path.

```
@main.route('/<path:page>')
def show(page):
    return render_template('%s.html' % page)
```

This will match

```
url_for('main.show', page='profile')
```

as well as

```
url_for('main.show', page='team/members')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add more than one route:

```
@main.route('/')
@main.route('/<page>')
def showpage(page=None):
   if page:
      # called with page parameter
      return render_template('%s.html' % page)
   else:
      # called with no parameters 
      return render_template('index.html')
```

On template:

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('main.showpage') }}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url_for('main.showpage', page='profile') }}">My Profile</a></li>
```

Comment: The problem is that I can ONLY render a template that is under template's root folder. If it's under another, ex: `template/user/profile.html`, `url_for('main.showpage', page='user/profile')` would return an error